# How to help recovery after long-distance cycling race?

Tags: recovery, bicycling, marathon

Yesterday I finished an anual bike race - 100km of cross-country riding with 6000m total elevation that many amateurs (over 2000) around here attempt. For most people it takes between 5 and 12 hours to finish and it is quite taxing. It's my 6th year doing it and while I usually manage to feel quite fine within 24 hours, some of my friends with less praparation complain of soreness and nausea for 2-3 days. What would be best strategy to recover after that? Including:

- How to decrease muscle and joint pain and cramps?
- How to treat inflamated legs / butt?

I imagine marathon recovery tactics might be similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marathon recovery for me is generally very very easy jogs, riding a bike, walks, stretching 2-3 times a day, drinking water, and massages.

Specifically stretching, massages, and light 30 min workouts of the affected muscles simply to get blood flowing in them are the keys in my opinion.

Its kinda funny that the best way to recover from this is to do more of it at an easy effort for 30 minutes. I still have doubts about this method before doing it while Im sore but it works pretty well everytime so far.

Id say reverse taper but if your friends weren't well prepared then telling them this likely wont be helpful to them.